# Couldn't access index.html in my WebContent folder

Tags: java, tomcat

I have tried to find a solution searching on Google, but did not succeed.

This is the structure of my application's folder.

```
<PROJECT_NAME>
--->WebContent
    --->index.html
    --->WEB-INF
    --->META-INF
```

I deployed my application in Tomcat server.

My web.xml config file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>fp</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FpServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.fp.FpServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FpServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I try to access localhost:8080/project_name/,and everything works fine, but when I try to access the index.html file like this `localhost:8080/project_name/index.html`, it doesn't show the index.html content. It shows my root project content. (localhost:8080/project_name/)

How can I get the index file content posted in the browser?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the folder is named "WEB-INF", not "WEB.INF".

Comment: Also **META-INF** instead of META.INF

Comment: Hi Thanks for the note. Its a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use default servlet to serve your static resources. Here is how this can be used with tomcat:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Hi, I added your mapping. Please see my edited question. But no luck

Comment: are you using tomcat?

Comment: Yes. apache-tomcat-6.0.37.  I added your mapping code into my old one.. pls see my edit. Is it correct?

Comment: edited my answer according to http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/default-servlet.html. Try this.

Comment: Hi, I used your answer. i added default servlet mapping Now showing 404 error eventhough for root path

Comment: what does your `FpServlet` is doing. is it some kind of front controller. is it needed for every request.

Comment: yes. Its a front controller. i just need to display the index.html file.  If i change the url pattern to /.*html then i can able to access index.html but localhost:8080/project_name doesn't work anymore

Comment: are you using plain jsp/servlet or is there any framework being used?